# Make curved street junctions in a cross styled junction in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have to make new city blocks based on buildings in a given area. The blocks have to be rectangular and their sides have to be parallel. Then I have to make this automated, so I have to convert that to Python, bad that's not a problem. I just can't fix something by hand.

[image: Blue are the buildings, purple is the road axis.]

I used :

- 2 Minimum Bound Geometry-Envelope, one to group the buildings in the block ( must have a common field), and one with all the building, to take the project area
- Converted both to lines
- Generated points along lines that group invidual city blocks
- Created a Thiessen polygon for these points, and dissolve the polygon based on their common field that is the number of the city block, and got the midline of the cityblocks, which is practically the centerline of road network of the area and turned that into line.

My problem is that in polygons edges the line of the roads makes a curve. Does anyone know how to delete the curved line and make lines straight, with an angle of intersection around 60-90 degrees?

I want to solve that cause I am going to make the city blocks by buffering the road axis to make my cityblocks.

With these curved road segments, my final polygons look like this :
[image]

TLDR: How can I make junctions from state 1 to state 2?
[image: 1) The curved street junction. 2) The kind of perpendicular way that I want road junction to be.]

I can work on ArcGIS Desktop Advanced and ArcGIS Pro Advance.

Comment: Try to simplify your roads, some will cut through houses though.

Comment: @FelixIP i tried to, but things got worse. I think i will try a new approach to the project by using the X,Y coordinates of the buildings and try to insert a line of best fit.